# Simulator is not running but still shows in use

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

In my xcode simulator no app is running,but when I try to run any app,this shows up-

"The simulator can't be launched because it is already in use"

I wanted to add a snapshot but i don't have 10 reputation

What can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Close simulator and relaunch xCode - will help

Comment: thanks.that worked!but can you tell me what happened?

Comment: this is xCode bug, usually happening when you will try to run app on simulator few times (run second before first loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Close the simulator and quit the xCode and relaunch it you then run your application again. It will help you. Some times the latest version of xCode having this kind of problem.